# Spring Cloud: use consul instead of eureka for service discovery with zuul

Tags: consul, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm implementing a Gateway with Zuul. The router is supposed to discover some micro services in order to satisfy the rules described in my `application.yml`. By default, Zuul is going to leverage Eureka, and this what my application does when starting.

I can read that `spring-cloud-consul` can be used also: `Supports Zuul, a dynamic router and filter via Spring Cloud Netflix`. However, there is no clear example that shows how to substitute consul to eureka. I added my dependency to my `pom.xml` in order to boostrap consul:

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RC1</version>
</dependency>`

However, when my application starts, it continues trying to contact eureka (my eureka server is stopped): `Can't get a response from http://localhost:8761/eureka/apps/MICROSERVICE-REST-API/xxxxxxx`

I'm probably missing some configuration point in order to tell zuul or ribbon to use consul.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: First of all Zuul doesnot leverage eureka by default. if your consul setup is correct then having this annotation should do the trick "@EnableDiscoveryClient" instead of "@EnableEurekaClient". Also you  will need to change the yml to look for consul instead of eureka.